# Not dispalying Maven Integration for eclipse (Juno and Newer) in eclipse juno version

Tags: m2eclipse

I installed eclipse juno version. And i tried to search in eclipse market place for "maven integration for eclipse (juno and newer)" version. but it is not showing. it is showing other versions like "maven integration for eclipse(lunar and newer)". but my project specific, i required juno and newer version.

can you give me ur comments..plzz

Regards,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

You can find the list of update site here https://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_updatesite_and_gittags

The m2e version for Juno is 1.1. To install in Eclipse : 
Help > Install New Software > Add the update site

and follow the wizard.

I think you can also try with 1.3.1. I think it will be compliant.